# With python, how do I find out if a string contains anything characters besides characters in another list

Tags: python, regex, pandas, contains

I have a list of characters:

```
example_list = ['a','b','c','1','2','3']
```

And I am running through a column in a pandas data frame iteratively and evaluating if something is "off". Lets call the column/list I am running through value. An example of the values I am looking through:

```
value1 = ['a12']
value2 = ['d88']
value3 = ['b33']
```

Values 1 and 3 would be correct, because they are only composed of elements from example_list. What I would like is for value2 to be flagged as False and values like 1 and 3 to be flagged as True.

What I have tried:

```
not any(x in example_list for x in value)
```

Which always seems to return True. Using an all() methodology will see if everything is in there and any() will find if any of them are in there, yes? I am looking for an "anything besides x" method. I am new to python, so I figure its a case of "I don't know, what I don't know", does anyone have any advice? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need `all` instead of `any`

Comment: The probelm is that you created list (for the values) so you check if the given string "a12" is in example_list that fails every time. so the negatedt any will return true. I think you want to change the lists to strings (remove the brackets)

Comment: You're thinking the wrong kind of all.  Think of it in words: for all characters in the target string, is the char in the list?  `ok = all(c in example_list for c in value1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `values` are lists of strings. That means, in each case you check if the **complete string** (like "a12") is included in the list of **single characters** => this is never True.

If you don't want to change the `values`, you can index the first string and then iterate over the letters of this string:

```
all(x in example_list for x in value1[0])  # => True
all(x in example_list for x in value2[0])  # => False
all(x in example_list for x in value3[0])  # => True
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood it right, each row contains a list with single element:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [['a12'], ['d88'], ['b33']]})
example_list = ['a','b','c','1','2','3']

print(df)

    value
0   [a12]
1   [d88]
2   [b33]
```

Then you could use a list comprehension:

```
df['check'] = [True if set(x[0]).issubset(set(example_list)) else False for x in df['value']]
```

We are checking if set of first element (so single value in your case) is subset of set of example_list and return True. False is returned when condition is not met.

Output:

```
    value   check
0   [a12]    True
1   [d88]   False
2   [b33]    True
```

Let me know if it is not what you meant or provide some simple input as a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = pd.Series(["a12", "d88", "b33"])
l = "".join(example_list)

>>> s
0    a12
1    d88
2    b33
dtype: object

>>> l
'abc123'

>>> s.apply(set(l).issuperset)
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution with what you started:

```
example_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3']

value1 = ['a12']
value2 = ['d87']
value3 = ['b33']

result=all(list(map(lambda x : True if x in example_list else False, *value2)))
print(result)
```

*value2 works with the list contet, so it is a string
*all is used to test that each character belongs to the example_list